# AMD Radeon R5M430 GPU error while attempting to use DRI_PRIME=1 -> Failed to allocate virtual address for buffer

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics, 19.04

I recently installed Ubuntu: **(19.04)**, and I immediately noticed that Ubuntu was never selecting my dedicated AMD GPU.

I started looking online for a solution, and I discovered `"DRI_PRIME=1"`, an environment variable to set before launching applications.

When I tried to use it to launch some OpenGL-based softwares, I ran into this error message:

```
radeon: Failed to allocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    alignment : 4096 bytes
radeon:    domains   : 4
radeon:    va        : 0x0000000100000000
radeon: Failed to deallocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    va        : 0x100000000
radeon: Failed to allocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    alignment : 4096 bytes
radeon:    domains   : 4
radeon:    va        : 0x0000000100000000
radeon: Failed to deallocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    va        : 0x100000000
radeonsi: Failed to create a context.
radeon: Failed to allocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    alignment : 4096 bytes
radeon:    domains   : 4
radeon:    va        : 0x0000000100000000
radeon: Failed to deallocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    va        : 0x100000000
radeon: Failed to allocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    alignment : 4096 bytes
radeon:    domains   : 4
radeon:    va        : 0x0000000100000000
radeon: Failed to deallocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    va        : 0x100000000
radeonsi: Failed to create a context.

X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  35
  Current serial number in output stream:  34
```

The error doesn't occur in all my programs. For example, VSCode launches without a problem even when I'm using DRI_PRIME=1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours of useless attemptings, I finally found a solution!

The solution to my problem is to add `radeon.runpm=0` to the file ***/etc/default/grub*** in the *GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT* section, and then add `DRI_PRIME=1` at the end of the file ***/etc/environment***.

Comment: Please remember to click the grey check mark that will appear next to your answer in two days.